# cannot read raw data from HTTP request with PHP/Apache

Tags: php, apache, httprequest

I was try to do a simple HTTP post with a integer and could not get it through to the PHP backend code as followed:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
$id = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo 'id: '.$id;
```

No matter what I posted, "echo 'id: '.$id;" returned this: "id: 
"

```
this.http.post('http://localhost/filename.php', 3);
```

Please help!

Comment: What makes you think your request was sent as JSON?

Comment: What Content-Type header is the request actually made with? `php://input` will not be populated when using `multipart/form-data` (unlikely here, but still worth checking.)

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/plain') is stated in the config.php file

Comment: it was a null without Jason_decode

Comment: _"header('Content-Type: text/plain') is stated in the config.php file"_ - that is the Content-Type your PHP script sets for the _response_ - has nothing whatsoever to do with what Content-Type header gets sent with the _request_.

Comment: I am novice in HTTP and is trying to work on others code, I could not find where was the Content-Type header coded. And if it was using multipart/form-data, can I modify it to send plain-text/Json data?

Comment: @CBroe: Inside a file Cors.php, I noted this codes below. Any impact to the post data? I tried adding a header for user validation but the result remain the same, NULL was received at the backend.         public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, Authorization, X-Requested-with, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
    }

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your hint, I studied on the internet for adding header, and was able to resolve the problem

Comment: @HokCheungHung would you care to post the answer and mark it as accepted? This way other community members can also benefit from what you learned.

Answer (score 0):

By adding headers content-type as application/json,

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
  .set('content-type', 'application/json');
```

I could get the raw data posted.

```
  ***getOrdersByUser(user) {
    console.log("added token header");
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('content-type', 'application/json');
    let postData = 4;
  
    return this.http.post('http://localhost/auth-app/myapps/backend/read_orders_by_user.php', user, {
      'headers': headers,
    });
 
    }***
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).